# CSS Link hover style

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a webpage which has a menu bar with links on the page. I have a style sheet for it but I'm having trouble with the "hover" code. A piece of my code looks like:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <a class="mLink" href="main.php">Home</a>
```

With a css code:

```
body {
background-color:black;
text-align: center;
height:100%;
}

div#wrapper{
margin-right: 5%;
margin-left: 5%;
margin-top: 0%;
margin-bottom: 5%;
border: outset;
border-color: white;
}

a.mLink{
color: white;
font-size: 35px;
padding: 10px;
}

a.mLink:hover{ 
color: black;
}

a.mLink:active{
color:black;
}


div#content{
color: white;
font-size: 40px;
}
```

The "hover" and "active" both aren't working and I don't understand why. I've tried a lot of different style variations such as a:hover, #menu a:hover, #menu a.mLink:hover, and nothing seems to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Is the color not changing for those states? What color is it staying with?

Comment: It should work, try to just type a:hover, and tell if it works.

Comment: It is white by default and I want it to change to some other color when hover and another when it is active(I currently have the hover and active as black for testing purposes) but the links are not changing color. Also a:hover does not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could include a screenshot of how it looks and tell us how it's supposed to look? I copied and pasted what you had into this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PQy5U/) and it works just fine to me. The only difference between what you posted and what I did was change the a:hover color to red and the a:active to yellow so you can see the difference instead of having black on black.

So can you post a screenshot of what's happening vs what you expect? If so, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: That's very strange. I tried it with different colors and it's still not working. The links are white by default and are not changing when I have the mouse over it. Could the browser effect it? I'm using Chrome

Comment: I'm using chrome too. Is there any way you can put what you have online? Other CSS might be interfering with what you have.

Comment: Funny enough my computer died. Plugged it in, turned it back on and now it works. However the active is just changing color when I click not if I'm on the page, is that what "active" is supposed to do or am I missing something?

Comment: That's exactly what active does. If you want it changed for when you're on the page, you'll have to make a new CSS class like "selected" and set your hyperlink's class to "selected".

Answer (score 0):

This may sound stupid, but clear the cache. It might be loading your previous version or something. Also what Web Browser is it? And is there any JS code that might dynamically change/add class.

Comment: How do you clear the cache? I'm using chrome and no, there is no JS code

Comment: @rsay3 just follow the guide:
http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95582